# Simple Open Auction example contract in Solidity docs doesn't pay beneficiary

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

I tried the Simple Open Auction example (https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/solidity-by-example.html#simple-open-auction) from the Solidity docs with ganache-cli and truffle. In migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js I set up:

```
var SimpleAuction = artifacts.require("./SimpleAuction.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(SimpleAuction, 300, "0xe6ebc74aa685527a83c9e0df01b21acf0a1e8286");
};
```

With "0xe6ebc74aa685527a83c9e0df01b21acf0a1e8286" the address of account 1 in ganache.

In truffle console, I executed the following commands to simulate an auction (and I waited 300 seconds before calling auction.auctionEnd(), which succeeded):

```
auction = SimpleAuction.at(SimpleAuction.address)
account1 = web3.eth.accounts[1]
account2 = web3.eth.accounts[2]
account3 = web3.eth.accounts[3]
account4 = web3.eth.accounts[4]
auction.bid({from: account2, value: web3.toWei(10, "ether")})
auction.bid({from: account3, value: web3.toWei(13, "ether")})
auction.bid({from: account4, value: web3.toWei(15, "ether")})
auction.withdraw({from: account2})
auction.withdraw({from: account3})
auction.auctionEnd()
web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(account1).toString(), "ether")
web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(account2).toString(), "ether")
web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(account3).toString(), "ether")
web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(account4).toString(), "ether")
```

After this, the balances are:

1. 100
2. 99.9936296
3. 99.9945537
4. 84.9945537

Account 4 has won the auction and paid 15 eth, but I expected account 1 to have a balance of 115 eth, because this account is the beneficiary. I suppose the example code, which I copied verbatim, doesn't have a bug, so what am I doing wrong here?

The contract code is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;

contract SimpleAuction {
    // Parameters of the auction. Times are either
    // absolute unix timestamps (seconds since 1970-01-01)
    // or time periods in seconds.
    address public beneficiary;
    uint public auctionEnd;

    // Current state of the auction.
    address public highestBidder;
    uint public highestBid;

    // Allowed withdrawals of previous bids
    mapping(address => uint) pendingReturns;

    // Set to true at the end, disallows any change
    bool ended;

    // Events that will be fired on changes.
    event HighestBidIncreased(address bidder, uint amount);
    event AuctionEnded(address winner, uint amount);

    // The following is a so-called natspec comment,
    // recognizable by the three slashes.
    // It will be shown when the user is asked to
    // confirm a transaction.

    /// Create a simple auction with `_biddingTime`
    /// seconds bidding time on behalf of the
    /// beneficiary address `_beneficiary`.
    constructor(
        uint _biddingTime,
        address _beneficiary
    ) public {
        beneficiary = _beneficiary;
        auctionEnd = now + _biddingTime;
    }

    /// Bid on the auction with the value sent
    /// together with this transaction.
    /// The value will only be refunded if the
    /// auction is not won.
    function bid() public payable {
        // No arguments are necessary, all
        // information is already part of
        // the transaction. The keyword payable
        // is required for the function to
        // be able to receive Ether.

        // Revert the call if the bidding
        // period is over.
        require(
            now <= auctionEnd,
            "Auction already ended."
        );

        // If the bid is not higher, send the
        // money back.
        require(
            msg.value > highestBid,
            "There already is a higher bid."
        );

        if (highestBid != 0) {
            // Sending back the money by simply using
            // highestBidder.send(highestBid) is a security risk
            // because it could execute an untrusted contract.
            // It is always safer to let the recipients
            // withdraw their money themselves.
            pendingReturns[highestBidder] += highestBid;
        }
        highestBidder = msg.sender;
        highestBid = msg.value;
        emit HighestBidIncreased(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    /// Withdraw a bid that was overbid.
    function withdraw() public returns (bool) {
        uint amount = pendingReturns[msg.sender];
        if (amount > 0) {
            // It is important to set this to zero because the recipient
            // can call this function again as part of the receiving call
            // before `send` returns.
            pendingReturns[msg.sender] = 0;

            if (!msg.sender.send(amount)) {
                // No need to call throw here, just reset the amount owing
                pendingReturns[msg.sender] = amount;
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /// End the auction and send the highest bid
    /// to the beneficiary.
    function auctionEnd() public {
        // It is a good guideline to structure functions that interact
        // with other contracts (i.e. they call functions or send Ether)
        // into three phases:
        // 1. checking conditions
        // 2. performing actions (potentially changing conditions)
        // 3. interacting with other contracts
        // If these phases are mixed up, the other contract could call
        // back into the current contract and modify the state or cause
        // effects (ether payout) to be performed multiple times.
        // If functions called internally include interaction with external
        // contracts, they also have to be considered interaction with
        // external contracts.

        // 1. Conditions
        require(now >= auctionEnd, "Auction not yet ended.");
        require(!ended, "auctionEnd has already been called.");

        // 2. Effects
        ended = true;
        emit AuctionEnded(highestBidder, highestBid);

        // 3. Interaction
        beneficiary.transfer(highestBid);
    }
}
```

When I call `auction.auctionEnd()` before the 300 seconds, I get an exception "Auction not yet ended", which is what it is supposed to do:

```
truffle(development)> auction.auctionEnd()
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert Auction not yet ended.
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:1)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:128:1)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-provider/wrapper.js:134:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:1
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:38:1)
```

When I call it after 300 seconds, I get a transaction and an event `AuctionEnded`, so it looks like the `now >= auctionEnd` condition is met:

```
truffle(development)> auction.auctionEnd()
{ tx: '0x480208cd6c4ac3580e7dcc3aa7e64cd0e7b5e11d5bea75e4769b554767158e35',
  receipt: 
   { transactionHash: '0x480208cd6c4ac3580e7dcc3aa7e64cd0e7b5e11d5bea75e4769b554767158e35',
     transactionIndex: 0,
     blockHash: '0xfde6956d9c7d6e99235606b70e11161965ddf832063e572a87df00c14484e5a1',
     blockNumber: 12,
     gasUsed: 76921,
     cumulativeGasUsed: 76921,
     contractAddress: null,
     logs: [ [Object] ],
     status: '0x1',
     logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000040000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' },
  logs: 
   [ { logIndex: 0,
       transactionIndex: 0,
       transactionHash: '0x480208cd6c4ac3580e7dcc3aa7e64cd0e7b5e11d5bea75e4769b554767158e35',
       blockHash: '0xfde6956d9c7d6e99235606b70e11161965ddf832063e572a87df00c14484e5a1',
       blockNumber: 12,
       address: '0xef0a6e95779240516e8a05039f97968f727c4f18',
       type: 'mined',
       event: 'AuctionEnded',
       args: [Object] } ] }
```

Comment: Please copy paste the contract in the question. Link may get broken or contract may get changed in time.

Comment: I would add a listener for the event `AuctionEnded`, to make sure that the event is being triggered.

Comment: Good point, ferit. I added the contract code.

Comment: How did you check that `auctionEnd()` succeed?

Comment: Found it, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this can help you. I think you missed time travel part.

```
// test/SimpleAuction.js

const sa = artifacts.require("SimpleAuction");

contract('SimpleAuction', async function(accounts) {

  /**
  * TimeTravel function - can move this to helper file
  * https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/6n65ar/using_testrpc_and_truffles_built_in_js_tests_how/dk7357l/
  */
  const timeTravel = function (time) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      web3.currentProvider.sendAsync({
        jsonrpc: "2.0",
        method: "evm_increaseTime",
        params: [time], // 86400 is num seconds in day
        id: new Date().getTime()
      }, (err, result) => {
        if(err){ return reject(err) }
        return resolve(result)
      });
    })
  }

  var sa_instance;
  var highest_bid = 2; // ether
  var bob         = accounts[1];
  var alice       = accounts[2];
  var john        = accounts[3];
  var beneficiary = accounts[accounts.length - 1]; // last account in Ganache
  var beneficiary_initial_balance;

  before(async function() {
    sa_instance = await sa.new(300, beneficiary);

    var bib_balance_wei = await web3.eth.getBalance(beneficiary);
    var bib_balance_eth = web3.fromWei(web3.toDecimal(bib_balance_wei), "ether");
    beneficiary_initial_balance = parseInt(bib_balance_eth);
  })

  it("Bob bids with 1 ETH", async function() {
    await sa_instance.bid({from: bob, value: web3.toWei(1, "ether")})
    var sa_balance_wei = await web3.eth.getBalance(sa_instance.address);
    var sa_balance_eth = web3.fromWei(web3.toDecimal(sa_balance_wei), "ether");
    assert.equal(sa_balance_eth, 1);
  })

  it("Alice bids with 2 ETH", async function() {
    await sa_instance.bid({from: alice, value: web3.toWei(highest_bid, "ether")})
    var sa_balance_wei = await web3.eth.getBalance(sa_instance.address);
    var sa_balance_eth = web3.fromWei(web3.toDecimal(sa_balance_wei), "ether");
    assert.equal(sa_balance_eth, 3);
  })

  it("Bob can withdraw his 1 ETH back", async function() {
    await sa_instance.withdraw({from: bob})
    var sa_balance_wei = await web3.eth.getBalance(sa_instance.address);
    var sa_balance_eth = web3.fromWei(web3.toDecimal(sa_balance_wei), "ether");
    assert.equal(sa_balance_eth, highest_bid);
  })

  it("Anyone can end the auction when it's due", async function() {
    await timeTravel(300);
    await sa_instance.auctionEnd({from: john});
  })

  it("Contract balance left with 0 ETH", async function() {
    var sa_balance_wei = await web3.eth.getBalance(sa_instance.address);
    var sa_balance_eth = web3.fromWei(web3.toDecimal(sa_balance_wei), "ether");
    assert.equal(sa_balance_eth, 0);
  })

  it("And beneficiary is now 2 ETH richer", async function() {
    var bib_balance_wei = await web3.eth.getBalance(beneficiary);
    var bib_balance_eth = web3.fromWei(web3.toDecimal(bib_balance_wei), "ether");
    var expected_new_beneficiary_balance = beneficiary_initial_balance + highest_bid;
    assert.equal(expected_new_beneficiary_balance, bib_balance_eth);
  })

})
```

Comment: Thanks! All tests in your test file are passing, so that's a reassurance. So there's something missing in my 'manual' test in truffle console...

Comment: I accepted your answer. I also upvoted both your and ferit's answer, but that doesn't seem to be visible because I'm a new user.

Answer (score 0):

Did `auctionEnd()` succeed?

Most likely `require(now >= auctionEnd)`  is not satisfied thus `auctionEnd()` failed.

---

**Update**: Debugged the contract myself, the transfer is successful. Beneficiary address is: `0xe6ebc74aa685527a83c9e0df01b21acf0a1e8286` not `account1`. So the contract works as expected, there is no problem. Check the balance of beneficiary address, you will see it has 15 ether.

**Clarification**:

This is the deployment instruction:

```
module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(SimpleAuction, 300, "0xe6ebc74aa685527a83c9e0df01b21acf0a1e8286");
};
```

So you set beneficiary address as: `0xe6ebc74aa685527a83c9e0df01b21acf0a1e8286`.

And this is the transfer instruction inside `auctionEnd()`:

`beneficiary.transfer(highestBid);`

So after the execution, if you run the following command you will see that beneficiary has 15 ether.

`web3.eth.getBalance("0xe6ebc74aa685527a83c9e0df01b21acf0a1e8286")`

> BigNumber { s: 1, e: 19, c: [ 150000 ] }

Comment: No that's not the problem, auctionEnd() did succeed. I clarified this in my question now.

Comment: Well, I doubt it. In the other answer Zulhilmi proposes to increase time, and if it solves your problem it means the require statement in my answer is unsatisfied, thus `auctionEnd()` was not successful. So actually I'm suggesting the same thing, you should satisfy the time constraint before calling `auctionEnd()`

Comment: I now added the output of truffle console when I call `auctionEnd()` before and after the 300 seconds.

Comment: Updated the answer, the problem is something else.

Comment: I appreciate you looking into it! But alas, I did the whole procedure again with the commands in truffle console, and I checked the balance of all addresses (now in Ganache-ui because it gives a better overview) and the 15 ether seems to have been lost somewhere. Could you tell me step by step what you did to be able to see that the transfer is successful? Sorry, but it really doesn't add up here.

Comment: No problem.  Wrote a clarification, let me know if you can't understand. @KoenVervloesem

Comment: But that's the thing... I completely understand your comments, but they just don't give the same results here. `web3.eth.getBalance("0xe6ebc74aa685527a83c9e0df01b21acf0a1e8286")` gives a balance of 100 ether, which was the balance in the beginning of the beneficiary.

Comment: Isn't `auction.auctionEnd()` enough to end the contract or am I missing something?

Comment: The balance of the beneficiary should be zero in the beginning. Are you sure? @KoenVervloesem

Comment: `auction.auctionEnd()` is enough. I run the same commands as in your question, nothing else.

Comment: Ganache sets the balance of all acounts to 100 in the beginning. After the listed commands with the highest bid of 15, account4 has balance 85 and account1 should have balance 115 but still has 100.

Comment: Look, please read carefully, the beneficiary address is not account1. It is not generated by ganache, you set it as a constant in deployment statement. @KoenVervloesem

Comment: It **is** the address of the beneficiary. As I stated in my question, I made sure that I set this address in the deployment statement to account 1 (note: not account 0) in Ganache. I really checked and double-checked all this before asking my question. Zulhilmi's test works here, so the contract works, but for some reason my 'manual test' in the truffle console doesn't seem to work and that bothers me, as I already checked a lot of the elementary errors I could make.

Comment: Did you migrate the contract when you start truffle console? @KoenVervloesem

Comment: Yes, I did :-) `truffle migrate --network development --reset`

Comment: No, after you open the console, just `migrate`. I don't know if there is a difference but maybe there is.

Comment: Actually, our seed phrases are different for Ganache. It is possible that account1 is beneficiary in your instance, but not necessarily.

At this point, I can't help as the problem is not reproducible. My instance works as expected.

Comment: Well I'm really out of options too. With `migrate` in the truffle console I get the same behaviour. Thanks anyway for thinking it through with me!